# problem running Tex on os 10.9.2

Tags: pdftex, emacs, auctex, mac

After installing OS 10.9.2 on my computer I can no longer use LaTeX. Every time I try to typeset a document I get an error message:

```
The program 'pdftex' was not found. Searched in directories: /usr/bin, /bin, /usr/sbin, /sbin, /usr/local/bin.

Check configuration of the pdfTex tool and path settings in the Preferences dialog.
```

I have seen an answer to this question. The problem is it involves going into the guts of LaTeX. Alas, while I love LaTeX I'm not tech savvy. Therefore I'm more than a little worried about tinkering with the program and losing access to many valuable documents.

Can someone provide a step by step answer for solving this problem. The current answer says to go to:

```
Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin /usr/texbin
```

I have easily found the `Library/Tex/Distributions` folder. There are 7 files within it... What do I do next.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Please provide a link to the answer you refer to. What you've said it says doesn't make much sense as you cannot go to 2 places at once! I'm guessing it is actually telling you to recreate symbolic links but I'd rather read the answer than guess since I'm not on OS X. Two other things. (1) **Documents you have not backed up are ones you are happy to lose.** Anytime. Especially during a system upgrade. But regardless. Hard drives, solid state drives, flash memory - it all dies. (2) Unless you keep your documents in strange places, you need not go near them to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This is a duplicate. In the linked question, you will find both a command line and a non-command line answer to it.  In your Applications/TeX folder there should be a package installer `FixMacTeX2013.pkg`. Run that, and it should solve the problem for you.